# Best way to store application state java

Tags: java

I have a java application which needs the 'TIME' last time my app has run.
i am running jar manually.Where should this last time run info can be stored .Should i store the last run time on file or some environment variables or some other?Please suggest best way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight-forward way would be with the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html). You won't need to care how the data is actually stored, or where.